# Spring Webflux concurrent access to shared resource

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I'm trying to implement a service that call to external API. There are two types of requests:
`client.authorize()` acquires a new token with lifetime 1 hour, `client.performRequest(..)` gets some data from API, requires authorization token acquired by `client.authorize()` request. Client class utilizes Spring Reactive `WebClient`.
Is it ok, to use `ReentrantLock` for synchronizing a block of code that checks and refreshes token if it's not fresh? Or it breaks reactive model? Maybe there are more convinient ways to organize access to common resource in reactive programming?

```java
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Service {

    private final Client client;

    @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    private Lock authLock = new ReentrantLock();
    @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    private String authToken;
    @Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    private LocalDateTime tokenExpirationDatetime;

    public Mono<Response> performRequest(Request request) {
        return preAuthorize()
                .flatMap(token -> client.performRequest(request, token));
    }

    private Mono<String> preAuthorize() {
        authLock.lock();
        try {
            if (existsActualToken()) {
                return Mono.just(authToken);
            }
            return refreshToken();
        } finally {
            authLock.unlock();
        }
    }

    private boolean existsActualToken() {
        return authToken != null
                && tokenExpirationDatetime.isAfter(LocalDateTime.now());
    }

    private Mono<String> refreshToken() {
        return client.authorize()
                .doOnNext(response -> {
                    this.authToken = response.token();
                    this.tokenExpirationDatetime = response.expirationDatetime();
                })
                .map(Response::token);
    }
}
```

Comment: As an alternative, Spring-webflux's Mono has the method `.cache(Duration ttl)`. So if you create a mono which retrieves a token, you can use .cache to use the cached value during the ttl-duration. I.e  create a field like `Mono<String> token = getToken().cache(Duration.of(...))`, where `getToken()` is some method that retrieves the token as a Mono<String>.

Comment: Can't you add a filter?

Comment: @ODDminus1 Nice solution! I've tried this, but `client.authorize()` is still being called after first request. ` public Mono<Response> performRequest(Request request) {
        return getToken()
                .flatMap(token -> client.performRequest(request, token));
    }

    private Mono<String> getToken() {
        return client.authorize()
.cache(response -> Duration.between(LocalDateTime.now(), response.expirationDatetime()),throwable -> Duration.ZERO,() -> Duration.ZERO)
.map(Response::token);
    }`

Comment: @K.Nicholas already tried, but will it make token check and refresh syncronized between threads?

Comment: You can also wrap authToken+tokenExpirationDatetime in a custom data class (like AuthData) and store them into AtomicReference/volatile. Then no lock is needed. Also consider return `Mono<String>` with authToken from `preAuthorize` and use its value in the next step instead of this.authToken

Comment: @gdomo Thanks for reply
1) But this doesn't synchronize read and write operations, so dirty read is possible. Thread 1 reads token - it's outdated, it starts requesting new token. Thread 2 reads token - it's still outdated, and it also starts requesting the new one. 
2) Nice tip. I've updated the code.

Comment: Regarding webflux's `.cache`: It might be a bit convoluted, since you neet to use the same instance of Mono<String> to use the cache. You could do it by configuring a bean of type Mono<String> which contains `.cache`.

Comment: I added an example of a simple app with webflux's cache as an answer bellow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a caching alternative, Spring-webflux contains an instance method in Mono to provide a simple cache with `Mono<T> cache(Duration ttl)`.

To use this, you must ensure that you are using the same instance of Mono for each retrivement of the cached value to actually use the cache. There are several ways to achieve this, but perhaps the most practical way is through configuring a bean for the Mono which fetches the token. A small application which applies this:

Test.java:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Test.class, args);
    }
}

@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
class Runner {
    private final Mono<String> auth;

    @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
    public void run() {
        Flux.<Request>generate(sink -> sink.next(new Request()))
                .flatMap(request -> auth.map(request::setAuth))
                .delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
                .doOnNext(request -> System.out.println("created request with auth: %s".formatted(request.getAuth())))
                .collectList()
                .block();
    }
}

@Data
class Request {
    String auth;
}

@RestController
class Controller {
    @GetMapping("/token")
    public Mono<String> createAuth() {
        return Mono.just("auth")
                .doOnNext(x -> System.out.println("created auth"));
    }
}

@Configuration
class Config {
    @Bean
    public WebClient webClient(WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder) {
        return webClientBuilder.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Mono<String> auth(WebClient webClient) {
        return webClient.get()
                .uri("http://localhost:8080/token")
                .retrieve().bodyToMono(String.class)
                .cache(Duration.ofSeconds(10));
    }
}
```